# Pod install resulting in "Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" during installation but files do not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, cocoapods

I'm having some issues with my cocoapods install since pulling from a new repo:

When i grab code from the repo on the new machine and try to run it straight off the bat i get errors with various missing files. Now this is expected as i have not committed the pods directory to the repo. So running the `pod install` command from terminal (in the project directory) remedies this issue for all but one of the dependencies, "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK".

When viewing the terminal text during the pod install i can see that it installs all other dependencies (installing "xxx" in green text) except for the google ads framework where it states:

> Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.6.0) in black text

Now navigating to the Podsproject Pods > Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK i see the directory is empty hence the build fails to compile due to missing `<GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>`

Is there a way i can force an install or is there a setting that is accidentally set somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit my podfile looks like this:

```
'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
pod "FBSDKCoreKit";
pod "FBSDKLoginKit";
pod "FBSDKShareKit";
pod "FBSDKMessengerShareKit";
```

Comment: what does your `Podfile` look like?

Comment: Hi Micheal i've updated my question. thanks

Comment: I'm still thinking about this; what happens if you change that line to "`pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK';`" and drop the version dependency?

Comment: Or change it to `7.6.0` ... that is the version mentioned in your terminal right?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tried both suggestions, make the change to the podfile in xcode, save and close xcode, cd to the directory and run pod install from the terminal, i get the same thing, however this time it states all the frameworks are "Using" probably because they are already installed. The Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK folder is still empty. Any more ideas as this is going to be an awful pain when cloning the repo to other macs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, amazingly enough it turns out it was a bad file folder config. Actively deleting the Google Mobile Ads SDK from Xcode didn't work, whilst it appeared to have been deleted it was still there in the project folder, manually finding the folder and removing it from the project then running "pod install" successfully reinstalled the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The PodFile you posted doesn't include the [source](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#source) keyword before the link to https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git.

If that's accurate, I'd wager it's preventing CocoaPods from loading the specs, which means it doesn't know where to get the Google Mobile Ads SDK.